# github - X ahead and X behind of master

Tags: git, github

I have a remote branch on my github called dev. I and a lot of people have made a lot of works on and now is not longer used. I would like to "syncro it" with the master branch but impossible.

This branch is  2 commits ahead,  10 behind of master.

```
This branch is  2 commits ahead,  10 behind of master.
```

I prefer ask because my master branch is on production with a lot of automation on it.

Is there a way directly from the CLI to do this stuff ? I would like avoid the fact to delete the branch and recreate it.

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can either [merge or rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/). In essence, it is

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

or

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
```

and fixing any possible conflicts.